# how to execute angular stuff in resolve of routePrvodier?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Once I execute angular stuff like trigger ng-click of an element use `element.click()`,it always says

```
"Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress".
```

But if I set a timeout with `setTimeout` function,this error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, this should solve your problem: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma. But are you saying you are using element.click() instead of ng-click, why is that? ng-click is a directive meant specifically for handling clicks within the angular digest cycle, why implement that yourself?

Comment: no , i truly used ng-click, but i have to trigger it ,then the only way i thought out is to use element.click().and ive tried the thing u said , doesnt work at all